# How to generate for loop number sequence by using variable names in bash?

Tags: bash, for-loop, sequences

Could anybody explain how can I use variable names in bash for loop to generate a sequence of numbers?

```
for year in {1990..1997}
do
  echo ${year}
done
```

Results:

1990
1991
1992
1993
1994
1995
1996
1997

However

```
year_start=1990
year_end=1997
for year in {${year_start}..${year_end}}
do
  echo ${year}
done
```

Results:

{1990..1997}

How can I make the second case work? otherwise I have to write tedious while loops.
Thanks very much.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use something like this

```
for (( year = ${year_start}; year <=${year_end}; year++ ))
do
  echo ${year}
done
```

`seq` command is outdated and best avoided.

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-for-loop/

And if you want real bad to use the following syntax,

```
for year in {${year_start}..${year_end}}
```

please modify it as follows:

```
for year in $(eval echo "{$year_start..$year_end}")
```

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-iterate-over-a-variable-range-of-numbers-in-bash/

Personally, I prefer using `for (( year = ${year_start}; year <=${year_end}; year++ ))`.

Answer (score 4):

Try following:

```
start=1990; end=1997; for year in $(seq $start $end); do echo $year; done
```

Comment: @chepner Would like to know the reason for not using backticks. Could they cause other problems?

Comment: `seq` command is outdated, and not recommended for `bash v3.x+`

Comment: @Sithsu They're hard to read, and hard to nest. There's no real reason to use them in place of `$( ... )`.